# Laravel 5 - List database entries using where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to list all entries which fall under a where condition.  If I do the following, I get all the entries returned

```
$users = User::lists('userName', 'id');
```

However, I am looking to return only the users who have a department id of 3.  So I am doing

```
$users = User::lists('userName', 'id')->where('departmentId', 3);
```

However, this returns an empty result set.  In my database, I do have users with this department id.

How can I get the lists statement working?

Just a note, the following returns the result I need

```
$users = User::select('userName', 'id')->where('departmentId', 3)->get();
```

However, in my edit form, because I have this

```
!! Form::select('csManager', $users, Input::old('users'), ['class' => 'csManager']) !!}
```

The old input is not selected and the data is showing up as an array.  I know the way to fix this is to do my select like this

```
<select class="csManager" name="csManager">
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->userName }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

But then I am not sure how to display the old user within the above select.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you switch the order to `$users = User::where('departmentId', 3)->lists('userName', 'id');` does it change anything?

Comment: That seems to work, why is this?

Comment: Same reason you can't use `->get()->where(...)`. `get()`, `first()`, `all()` and `lists()` are all closures, which finalize and execute the query. Logically, you can't call `where()` on a query that has already returned results.

Answer (score 1):

To mark a old selection try this:

```
<option value="{{ $user->id }}" 
         {{ (Input::old('users') == $user->id)? 'selected' : '' }}>
    {{ $user->userName }}
</option>
```

As @TimVanUum say, you can save a little bit of code if you prefer. Both are equals.

```
<option value="{{ $user->id }}" 
         {{ (Input::old('users') !== $user->id)?: 'selected'}}>
    {{ $user->userName }}
</option>
```

Comment: However this is more readable you could also do ! == and then ?: 'selected'  wich saves you a little bit of code. It's what you prefer, but I like my in-line statement as short as possible. To prevent a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$users = User::where('departmentId', 3)->lists('userName', 'id');
```

In blade form:

```
{!! Form::select('csManager', $users, null, ['class' => 'csManager']) !!}
```

To get the old data in edit form instead of

```
{!! Form::open([your attributes]) !!}
```

Use model binding. something like this:

```
{!! Form::model($user,[your attributes]) !!}
```

> In this case your edit method should have `$user=findOrFail($id);`